# JBoss 7.1 Liquibase in memory does not restart with server restart

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, persistence, liquibase, changelog

I have a problem with JBoss 7.1 and Liquibase.

I have my base stored in memory, but after I restart server database isn't restarted and I'm having errors according to creating tables which already exists.

My changelog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">


<changeSet id="1" author="dobiesl">
    <createTable tableName="ksiazka">
        <column name="id" type="int">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="tytul" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="rok_wydania" type="int">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="dostepnosc" type="int">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="2" author="dobiesl">
    <insert tableName="ksiazka">
        <column name="id" type="int" value="1">
        </column>
        <column name="tytul" type="varchar(50)" value="Pan Tadeusz">
        </column>
        <column name="rok_wydania" type="int" value="1999">
        </column>
        <column name="dostepnosc" type="int" value="1">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="ksiazka">
        <column name="id" type="int" value="2">
        </column>
        <column name="tytul" type="varchar(50)" value="W pustyni i w puszczy">
        </column>
        <column name="rok_wydania" type="int" value="1999">
        </column>
        <column name="dostepnosc" type="int" value="1">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="ksiazka">
        <column name="id" type="int" value="3">
        </column>
        <column name="tytul" type="varchar(50)" value="Ogniem i mieczem">
        </column>
        <column name="rok_wydania" type="int" value="2001">
        </column>
        <column name="dostepnosc" type="int" value="1">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="ksiazka">
        <column name="id" type="int" value="4">
        </column>
        <column name="tytul" type="varchar(50)" value="Pan Wolodyjowski">
        </column>
        <column name="rok_wydania" type="int" value="1975">
        </column>
        <column name="dostepnosc" type="int" value="1">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="ksiazka">
        <column name="id" type="int" value="5">
        </column>
        <column name="tytul" type="varchar(50)" value="Potop">
        </column>
        <column name="rok_wydania" type="int" value="1998">
        </column>
        <column name="dostepnosc" type="int" value="0">
        </column>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="3" author="dobiesl">
    <createTable tableName="autor">
        <column name="id" type="int">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="imie" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="nazwisko" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="4" author="dobiesl">
    <insert tableName="autor">
        <column name="id" type="int" value="1">
        </column>
        <column name="imie" type="varchar(50)" value="Adam">
        </column>
        <column name="nazwisko" type="varchar(50)" value="Mickiewicz">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="autor">
        <column name="id" type="int" value="2">
        </column>
        <column name="imie" type="varchar(50)" value="Henryk">
        </column>
        <column name="nazwisko" type="varchar(50)" value="Sienkiewicz">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="autor">
        <column name="id" type="int" value="3">
        </column>
        <column name="imie" type="varchar(50)" value="Stefan">
        </column>
        <column name="nazwisko" type="varchar(50)" value="Zeromski">
        </column>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="5" author="dobiesl">
    <createTable tableName="ksiazka_autor">
        <column name="aid" type="int">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="kid" type="int">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="6" author="dobiesl">
    <insert tableName="ksiazka_autor">
        <column name="aid" type="int" value="1">
        </column>
        <column name="kid" type="int" value="1">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="ksiazka_autor">
        <column name="aid" type="int" value="2">
        </column>
        <column name="kid" type="int" value="2">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="ksiazka_autor">
        <column name="aid" type="int" value="2">
        </column>
        <column name="kid" type="int" value="3">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="ksiazka_autor">
        <column name="aid" type="int" value="2">
        </column>
        <column name="kid" type="int" value="4">
        </column>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="ksiazka_autor">
        <column name="aid" type="int" value="2">
        </column>
        <column name="kid" type="int" value="5">
        </column>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Persistence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="pl.biblioteka.baza" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- the JNDI data source -->
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <!-- if this is true, hibernate will print (to stdout) the SQL it executes, 
            so you can check it to ensure it's not doing anything crazy -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <!-- since most database servers have slightly different versions of the 
            SQL, Hibernate needs you to choose a dialect so it knows the subtleties of 
            talking to that server -->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" 
            /> -->
        <!-- this tell Hibernate to update the DDL when it starts, very useful 
            for development, dangerous in production -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

jboss configuration:

```
      <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Why I'm having this errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

Here was the problem. Hibernate was creating tables from entities before liquibase could do it.